# how change uri that http_listener listen to it

Tags: c++, casablanca

I use http_listener of cpprest(casablanca) library as my server.
after some request from client I want to change uri that this listener listen to it in handle_post of listener.
In main.cpp I have this code:

```
    changeIpOrPort = 0;


try
{

    while (true){

        web::http::experimental::listener::http_listener *MyListener = new web::http::experimental::listener::http_listener(uri("http://"+MyserverIpaddress+":"+MyserverPort+"/"));
        MyListener->support(methods::GET, handle_get);
        MyListener->support(methods::POST, handle_post);

        MyListener
                ->open()
                .then([&MyListener]() {TRACE(L"\n Again starting to listen\n"); })
                .wait();

        std::cout <<"current ip server is :"<<MyserverIpaddress<<" current port is "<< MyserverPort  <<endl;
        changeIpOrPort = 0;
        while(changeIpOrPort == 0);
        MyListener->close();
        delete(MyListener);

    }

}
catch (exception const & e)
{
    wcout <<L"exception is " <<e.what() << endl;
}
```

in handle_post function that define in source.cpp , when I recognize that client want change server Ip address , I set changeIpOrPort to 1.
but i raise an exception :
bind: Cannot assign requested address

does anybody know why this exception raise and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to setup a new `http_listener` if the IP address needs to be changed.

Comment: I change my code and  create new http_listener in main.cpp.  but it did not work correctly